# Instances of React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I have this app component:

```
function App() {
  const [ active, setActive ] = useState('student')
  const [ row, setRow ] = useState(true)
  const [ currentComponent, setCurrentComponent ] = useState(<Table setRow={setRow} represent="students" />)
  const [ contextData, setContextData ] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    switch (active) {
      case 'student':
        setCurrentComponent(<Table setRow={setRow} represent="students" />)
        return
      case 'employee':
        setCurrentComponent(<Table setRow={setRow} represent="employees" />)
        return
      case 'class':
        setCurrentComponent(<div>class</div>)
        return
    }
  }, [ active ])

  return (
    <appContext.Provider value={{ contextData, setContextData }} >
        <div className="App">
          { row ? <TabRow setActive={setActive} active={active} /> : "" }
          { currentComponent }
        </div>
    </appContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

I just realized that the Table component does not mount and unmount between 'student' as active and 'employee' as active. Does this mean that the component only re renders since props change?

Comment: Please show `<TableRow>` component code. You're side effect specified by `useEffect` will trigger only when `active` prop changes *to a different value*. If you call `setActive` and you change active from `student` to `employee` then effect will trigger and according to the switch one of the `setCurrentComponent` executed. Then the component will be rerender after state change

Answer (score 1):

Rendered components should not be stored in state, that will lead to unexpected behavior in React. Make sure all components render all the time and only store non-components in state:

- see [What *Shouldn't* Go in State](https://web.archive.org/web/20150419023006/http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html#what-shouldnt-go-in-state)

```js
function App() {
  const [ active, setActive ] = useState('student')
  const [ row, setRow ] = useState(true)
  const [ contextData, setContextData ] = useState({});

  let currentComponent;
  switch (active) {
    case 'employee':
      currentComponent = <Table setRow={setRow} represent="employees" />
      return
    case 'class':
      currentComponent = <div>class</div>
      return
    case 'student':
    default:
      currentComponent = <Table setRow={setRow} represent="students" />
      return
  }

  return (
    <appContext.Provider value={{ contextData, setContextData }} >
        <div className="App">
          { row ? <TabRow setActive={setActive} active={active} /> : "" }
          { currentComponent }
        </div>
    </appContext.Provider>
  );
}
```